# implement Dart class from a flutter UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i got this example code dart class from HivMq(an MQTT Cluster service provider) that perform publish and subscribe task in its simplest form.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';

// main() {
//   MQTTClientWrapper newclient = new MQTTClientWrapper();
//   newclient.prepareMqttClient();
// }

// connection states for easy identification
enum MqttCurrentConnectionState {
  IDLE,
  CONNECTING,
  CONNECTED,
  DISCONNECTED,
  ERROR_WHEN_CONNECTING
}

enum MqttSubscriptionState { IDLE, SUBSCRIBED }

class MQTTClientWrapper {
  MqttServerClient client;

  MqttCurrentConnectionState connectionState = MqttCurrentConnectionState.IDLE;
  MqttSubscriptionState subscriptionState = MqttSubscriptionState.IDLE;

  // using async tasks, so the connection won't hinder the code flow
  void prepareMqttClient() async {
    _setupMqttClient();
    await _connectClient();
    _subscribeToTopic('Dart/Mqtt_client/testtopic');
    _publishMessage('Hellodsfsdfdsg');
  }

  // waiting for the connection, if an error occurs, print it and disconnect
  Future<void> _connectClient() async {
    try {
      print('client connecting....');
      connectionState = MqttCurrentConnectionState.CONNECTING;
      await client.connect('*******', '******');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('client exception - $e');
      connectionState = MqttCurrentConnectionState.ERROR_WHEN_CONNECTING;
      client.disconnect();
    }

    // when connected, print a confirmation, else print an error
    if (client.connectionStatus.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
      connectionState = MqttCurrentConnectionState.CONNECTED;
      print('client connected');
    } else {
      print(
          'ERROR client connection failed - disconnecting, status is ${client.connectionStatus}');
      connectionState = MqttCurrentConnectionState.ERROR_WHEN_CONNECTING;
      client.disconnect();
    }
  }

  void _setupMqttClient() {
    client = MqttServerClient.withPort(
        '**************************.hivemq.cloud', '******', 8883);
    // the next 2 lines are necessary to connect with tls, which is used by HiveMQ Cloud
    client.secure = true;
    client.securityContext = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
    client.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
    client.onDisconnected = _onDisconnected;
    client.onConnected = _onConnected;
    client.onSubscribed = _onSubscribed;
  }

  void _subscribeToTopic(String topicName) {
    print('Subscribing to the $topicName topic');
    client.subscribe(topicName, MqttQos.atMostOnce);

    // print the message when it is received
    client.updates.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
      final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c[0].payload;
      var message =
          MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);

      print('YOU GOT A NEW MESSAGE:');
      print(message);
    });
  }

  void _publishMessage(String message) {
    final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builder.addString(message);

    print(
        'Publishing message "$message" to topic ${'Dart/Mqtt_client/testtopic'}');
    client.publishMessage(
        'Dart/Mqtt_client/testtopic', MqttQos.exactlyOnce, builder.payload);
  }

  // callbacks for different events
  void _onSubscribed(String topic) {
    print('Subscription confirmed for topic $topic');
    subscriptionState = MqttSubscriptionState.SUBSCRIBED;
  }

  void _onDisconnected() {
    print('OnDisconnected client callback - Client disconnection');
    connectionState = MqttCurrentConnectionState.DISCONNECTED;
  }

  void _onConnected() {
    connectionState = MqttCurrentConnectionState.CONNECTED;
    print('OnConnected client callback - Client connection was sucessful');
  }
}
```

what i did was to comment out the main() function in the dart file and instantiate the class in a flutter app instance to call the member functions of the class at every tap of a flutter button, its not working as expected, but when i run the dart file independently it work as expected.
here is the flutter code bellow where i instantiate the dart class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_test/mqttService/mqtt_strm.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MQTT PUB SUB Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'MQTT  Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MQTTClientWrapper newclient = MQTTClientWrapper();
  bool _counter = true;
  String _pubTopic = "testTopic";

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter = !_counter;
      _counter ? publish(_pubTopic, "1") : publish(_pubTopic, "0");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            const Text(
              'Published to MQTT',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  void publish(String topic, String value) {
    // myMqtt.publish(topic, value);
    print("calling mqttService");
    newclient.prepareMqttClient();
  }
}
```

please i need help on how to make this dart file work with flutter, i am very much new to dart and flutter

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Do you get error messages?

Comment: it doesn't publish the topic, but when i run just the dart file it does

Comment: Well, you don't actually call the publish method, so... not sure what you expect?

Comment: i called the newclient.prepareMqttClient() method which in turn call the publish and subscribe method

Comment: hm, just an observation, probably not your problem: that method should make your linter scream and die. void/async is a bad combination. Since it apparently doesn't, you should a) get your linter straightened out, and b) take code from a better source, this is written by someone who doesn't do Dart well.

Comment: Do you see any of the print statement by the way? Where exactly does it fail?

Comment: i cant get the print statements to show up on my terminals, only the print statement from the flutter show up on my terminal

Comment: the print statement from the dart class doesnt show up